# Google Analytics Data to PHP Page

Tags: google-analytics, google-api

I have a multi author blog where I track each author and their adsense revenue in Google Analytics using custom variables. I was wondering if I can use Google Analytics API to export those data to a PHP page with this format:

```
Author | Revenue
------------------
Jean   | $3.21
Sammy  | $1.43
Mona   | $7.21
```

How can I do it?

Comment: You better explain your question better otherwise the answer is a simple "Yes"

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to use the API library Google put together:

http://analytics.blogspot.com/2012/05/new-google-analytics-easy-dashboard.html